# Masonry breaks on percentage layout

Tags: javascript, jquery-masonry, masonry

In the [documentation for Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#columnwidth), it says that to use percentage based widths, you should use a CSS class to define it, i.e.,

```
.col-width {
  width: 16.71827%;
}

var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector: '.tile',
    columnWidth: '.col-width',
});
```

However, trying to do that seems to break my layout every time where all the blocks are stacked on top of each other. [Here's a Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/marcelosomers/pen/FDsKm).

Any ideas on what is going wrong here?